# FIrefox is not displaying files and commands on Github properly

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, github, fonts

To my suprise when I open (at least any, that I have tried) Github repository there is problem (concretely there is **no** text displayed) with the text that is marked as command, like this (the grey boxes should not be empty):
[image: inline command not displayed on github]

And also any code file (with any extension) is not displayed at all or it is not displayed correctly, see (there are coloured squares instead of text):
[image: code displayed incorrectly on github]

And this happens only in Firefox. Google chrome displays everything, as far as I can tell, properly.

There might be some connection with fonts (btw. I am using Ubuntu). Recently, I have been having troubles with TeXLive and I have manually deleted many files (including some fonts) in order to achieve reinstall (did not go as planned). But I can't tell you, what precisely I have removed (my bad). After that I've noticed missing TeXGyreAdventor font in LibreWriter, so I've installed it manually.

The only thing I did to Firefox was running the command:

```
apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

which did not fix it (the screenshots are after the reinstall).

Any ideas how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: this is more suited for superuser

Comment: oh, sure, my bad! What was I thinking.

Comment: No worries, your question will probably be *magically* migrated ;)

Comment: I can reask it there, half way through and then delete this one. Or shouldn't I?

Comment: I would wait a little (ca 24h) and if not migrated automagically, then delete and ask on superuser (but that's only my opinion)